# Selecionar tipo de colunas que vem em um SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

Olá, minha duvida é a seguinte:

Tenho um Select no SQLServer de duas tabelas com inner join, elas me retornam um conjunto de 5 colunas. Gostaria de saber como faço pra listar o tipo dessas colunas.

Sei que tem como mostrar o tipo das colunas com `SP_Columns`, porém ele só me mostra se o parametro passado for uma tabela ou view.

Meu select é esse:

```
SELECT *
FROM Produtos p
INNER JOIN Marca m
ON p.prodcodigo=m.prodcodigo
```

Comment: Quando você faz uma query ou um cursor para recuperar valores no SQL Server, você precisa definir os tipos das variáveis que receberão esses valores. Em T-SQL puro não creio ser possível fazer isso a não ser, talvez, com uma imensa gambiarra de geração de queries dinâmicas. Por outro lado, se você estiver acessando o banco com uma linguagem de programação seria possível acessar os meta-dados da query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a tabela de metadados `SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, porém não conseguirá relacionar com sua tabela. Há duas alternativas para isso.

Na primeira, será necessário fazer múltiplas queries, até obter o resultado desejado.
Na segunda, cria-se uma coluna em seu banco, guardando o tipo de dado, como valor.

Comment: Eu fiz uma view com a query, depois usei o SP_Columns pra ver o resultado.